# How to use whole numbers in a formula, and the result be a float with accurate two decimal digits?

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

so my goal here is to write program that solves quadratic equations. But the values corresponding to a, h, and k must be whole numbers While the value of x must be a double precision real number with two decimal digit.

My problem occurs when I run the ints through the formula it just return me whole numbers. I know that if i change the ints from ints into doubles the program runs correctly but my professor wants them to be Whole numbers .

```
#include <iostream>             
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int  main( )
{
int a = 3,h = 4,k = 5 ;
double x1;

x1 = -h + sqrt(k/a);
x1 = round(x1*100.00)/100.00;

cout << "The solutions for the equation are: " << endl << "                            " << "x1: " <<setprecision(2) << fixed << x1;

}
```

Comment: *"so my goal here is to write program that solves quadratic equations"* -- That's nice, but irrelevant to your question. Focus on your problem (*"when I run the ints through the formula it just return me whole numbers"*). Don't give us the code to solve quadratic equations (especially don't waste our time asking for our name). Give us just a demonstration that the formula returns whole numbers. Pick an example case, initialize `a`, `h`, and `k` to those values (no user input necessary) and show the result of the formula. Just one formula, not both `x1` and `x2`. See also [mre].

Comment: Thank you , I took your advice and cleaned it up I apologize it was just lazy of me copy and pasting my assignment for the most part, I cleaned it up and hopefully made it much more legible and will be doing so with my questions from now on.

Comment: Better. Another useful improvement would be specifying the actual and expected results. Especially since you seem to want your program to display whole numbers accurate to two digits after the decimal point. Which is weird because for any whole number, the digits after the decimal point are zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static_cast<double>`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string name;
    int a, h, k;
    double x1, x2;

    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the known terms for the quadratic equation" << endl;
    cout << "a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl << "h: ";
    cin >> h;
    cout << endl << "k: "; 
    cin >> k;

    cout << endl << "Thanks, " << name << "";
    // Calculates x1 using the formula -h + square root(k/a)
    x1 = -h + sqrt(static_cast<double>(k)/a);
    // Rounds x1 to the second decimal digit and reassigns it to x1
    x1 = round(x1*100.00)/100.00;
    // Ditto for x2
    x2 = -h - sqrt(static_cast<double>(k)/a);
    x2 = round(x2*100.00)/100;
    cout << "The solutions for the equation are: " << endl << "                            " << "x1: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << x1;
    cout << endl << "                            " << "x2: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << x2;
}
```

Because both of the operands were integers, it used integer division, which rounds afterwards. By casting one operand to `double`, we use regular division.

Other comments: I fixed the formula for `x2`, which used `+` instead of `-`. Also, I did a bit of indentation and other formatting. This was a case of ridiculous over-commenting; I know what most of those lines do, they aren't that complicated. I removed most of the unnecessary comments.

Comment: Integer division doesn’t round at all — [its behavior is different than floating-point division](https://marcelkliemannel.com/articles/2021/dont-confuse-integer-division-with-floor-division/). ([In C and C++ it truncates toward zero.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators))

Comment: @Dúthomhas truncation towards zero is a form of rounding

Comment: @pigrammer Yes, but the machine operation to implement integer division does not involve rounding. (Sorry, I didn’t mean to split fine hairs here.)